# How to Automate Checking for Stolen Content?

Tags: google, copyright

So I know about tools like Copyscape and Google Alerts.. great tools, but it's quite tedious for me to copy and paste an URL or phrase for every one of my pages in my sites. Is there any tool out there that monitors your website and emails you or alerts you whenever someone has stolen content from your site?

The only service I know is CopySentry and honestly, it's too expensive for me since I got thousands of pages I want to monitor...

Anyone else have this problem? or is it just me?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Google Alerts](http://www.google.com/alerts). Put in some text that is unique to your content and Google will then alert you when new content is found that matches that text.

Comment: I know about Google Alerts. But the problem is it takes too long to go through every single page.

Comment: @Hisoka - If you want free or inexpensive you're going to have to settle for less then perfect.

Comment: I don't really care about cost... I just want to know automated monitoring alternatives

Answer (score -1):

You can use Copyscape or Plagium :
http://www.copyscape.com/
http://www.plagium.com/

Google Alert is a good choice too if you can automate it.

Comment: Hisoka already said that was too expensive.